# case when query in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to execute below query,
when date diff is greater than 1 , how to add that in when clause as diffdate is not available there.

```
select 
   CASE ( 
SELECT DATEDIFF('2014-11-30','2015-11-29') AS DiffDate
 )
   WHEN 1 THEN "1 Day"
   WHEN 7 THEN "Week"
   WHEN ??? THEN "Yearly"


   END;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an `else`

```
select CASE DATEDIFF('2014-11-30','2015-11-29')
            WHEN 1 THEN '1 Day'
            WHEN 7 THEN '7 Days'
            ELSE 'Yearly'
       END;
```

Comment: Basically I have more conditions, so dont want to use else. Is it possible using when?

Comment: like when datediff is 7 then "week" and if it more than 7 then "yearly".

Comment: is it possible to do it in when tag like DiffDate>7 - "yearly"

Comment: `select CASE 
            WHEN DATEDIFF('2014-11-30','2015-11-29') = 1 THEN '1 Day'
            WHEN DATEDIFF('2014-11-30','2015-11-29') = 7 THEN '7 Days'
            WHEN DATEDIFF('2014-11-30','2015-11-29') > 7 THEN 'Yearly'
       END;`